# Generate Rust code during the build.rs stage

Tags: c, rust, cross-compiling, rust-cargo

I am trying to wrap a C library using Rust's `build.rs` code. During the `configure`  stage, it is possible to set up a bunch of flags, say `MAX_LEVEL=5`, `DERIVATION=2`. In this case, a script will generate an array of pointer-to-function in the C code, e.g.

```c
#define MAX_LEVEL 5

void (*evaluate_level[MAX_LEVEL])(/* args */);
void (*derivation_1[MAX_LEVEL])(/* args */);
void (*derivation_2[MAX_LEVEL])(/* args */);
```

where the level `i` value is evaluated by calling `evaluate_level[i](&arg)` whereas the first/second order derivation is evaluated using `derivation_1[i](&arg)` and `derivation_2[i](&arg)`. Higher-order derivations can be supported by increasing the `DERIVATION` and recompiling the library.

Now in my Rust wrapper, `lib.rs`, I would like to

- Know the `MAX_LEVEL` is set to 5, e.g. creating a `pub const MAX_LEVEL: u32 = 5;` statement somewhere; or, have a crate function `pub fn get_max_level() -> u32 { 5 }`.
- Also, either generate the `derivation` code by setting up

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct EvaluateArg(/* private fields */);


const DERIVATION: [fn(u32, *mut EvaluateArg); 2] = [/* ... */];
```

or having

```
pub const MAX_DERIVATIONS: u32 = 2;

pub fn derivation_1(level: u32, arg: &mut EvaluateArg);
pub fn derivation_2(level: u32, arg: &mut EvaluateArg);
```

using either a macro or some other ways, e.g. manually generating the code?

Is this possible by setting up `build.rs` in some certain way?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. (Do you maybe want to look at an [example](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-bindgen/tutorial-3.html) of a crate that does this for you?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Caesar mentioned in the comment, the standard library `bindgen` will parse the C++ header file via `clang` and generate the corresponding binding Rust code.